# Ubuntu 14.04 Freeze i/o error

Tags: dual-boot, freeze

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 and I have been getting periodic system hangups and freezes. When I press F1 it will display i/o errors and sometimes display "Failed Command: Read FPDMA Queued." What usually happens next is that I am unable to use the gui or type in commands in terminal. The only solution is to use reisub  to restart.

I am dual booting with Windows 7 using the same HDD and I have no problems with it. I have scanned the drive using GSmartControl and it shows no errors in extended Self-tests or any other test type.

I have also applied updates, changed drivers, and reinstalled twice (one was mint 17). I have formatted the partition and scanned it using Windows and no errors came up.

I am unsure what to do in order to solve this. If my drive is failing, then why am I getting no errors when I scan it? Also why does Windows 7 work flawlessly on it?

Comment: Partly solved by formatting HDD and installing Mint instead of Ubuntu, so voting no-repro

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the solution to my problem. I'm not quite sure what it was, but it seems to be related to the hard drive.

First, I used Ultimate Boot CD, and wiped my drive by overwriting everything with 0s. Then I formatted my drive for a dual boot with Windows 7.

I have been playing around in my installation for about 2 hours now, and so far I am crash and system freeze free. Although, I do get an occasional GUI freeze during certain tasks that load the hard drive, but it seems to be no different than what happens in Windows.

While I am not running Ubuntu at the time, I am running Mint 17 which is similar.